# How to get current customer in external file

Tags: magento-1.9, module, customer-account, external

In my module i have a php file which is called by an Ajax Post, after a user has clicked on a link.
Now i need the customer-ID of that user who has clicked on this link.

```
    require_once("../../../../../Mage.php");
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
```

Returns false at the same time at my phtml file with the same code it Returns true. I have tried other ways like

```
       Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
        if((Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())) {
            $productPriceString = "true";
        } else {
            $productPriceString = "false";
        }
```

or even

```
    define('ROOT',Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB));
    $coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

    if(isset($coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'])){
        $customerId = $coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'];
    } else {
        header('Location: '.ROOT.'customer/account/login/');
    }

    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customerId);

    $customerSession = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
    if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        header('Location: '.ROOT.'customer/account/login/');
    }
```

But the result was always the same. So my question how can i get the id or even the _Customer object.

Thanks

EDIT

```
$session= Mage::getSingleton("core/session");
```

The result in my phtml file is object(Mage_Core_Model_Session)#125 (8)
But the result in my external php file is object(Mage_Core_Model_Session)#145 (8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have runned this script and it's working. It provides me the customer id. Before you run it, delete the `cache` and `session` folders under you `var` folder

```
<?php
require_once ( "app/Mage.php" );
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

if($session->isLoggedIn())
{
    echo $session->getCustomer()->getId();
}else{
    echo "Not logged in";
}
```

Comment: Deleting `var/session` is never an appropiate solution. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session

Comment: This morning I've started checking my oldest answers. Soon, I discovered this answer and I labeled it as "I'm not proud of it". Definitely a bad idea to entirely remove the var/session. Thank you for the review :D.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
require_once ( "/your-magento-directory/app/Mage.php" );
umask(0);

// Initialize Magento
Mage::app("default");

// You have two options here,
// "frontend" for frontend session or "adminhtml" for admin session
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$isLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session")->isLoggedIn();
```

Comment: This does not work. Im logged in and the result is still false.

Answer (score 0):

I have used it one of my projects like this hope might help you

**Customer Session :**

```
<?php
// Include Magento application
require_once ( "app/Mage.php" );//path to your magento Mage.php file
umask(0);

// Initialize Magento
Mage::app();

// You have two options here,
// "frontend" for frontend session or "adminhtml" for admin session
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));

$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

if($session->isLoggedIn())
{
    echo "Logged in";
}else{
    echo "Not logged in";
}
```

**Magento Session from external page (same domain)**

```
<?php
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app(); 

// Define the path to the root of Magento installation.
define('ROOT', Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB));

// Obtain the general session and search for an item called 'customer_id'
$coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
if(isset($coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'])){
    $customerId = $coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'];
} else {
    header('Location: '.ROOT.'customer/account/login/');
}

// Load the user session.
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customerId);
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

// We verified that created successfully (not required)
if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    header('Location: '.ROOT.'customer/account/login/');
}

// Load customer
$customer = $customerSession->getCustomer();

// We get cell phone
$telefono = $customer->getTelefonoMovil();
?>
```

Comment: I tried your solution already in the past but this is not working for me :-( i have absolutely no idea why

Answer (score 0):

(this would be in a comment but not enough rep to comment at the time of writing)

The popular code snippet worked for me, but only when the file containing the snippet is in the **same folder as the Magento install**.  I suspect( hope) there is a way to configure the base install dir in Magento to allow for doing this outside the mage root folder.

```
<?php
require_once ( "app/Mage.php" );
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

if($session->isLoggedIn())
{
    echo $session->getCustomer()->getId();
}else{
    echo "Not logged in";
```

}